# Why is my .htaccess file not redirecting?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have never used or modified the .htaccess file before.

I am creating a very basic registration and login page.

This is what my .htaccess page contains:

```
Redirect /sitemap.txt /index.php
Redirect /userpwd.txt /index.php
Redirect /activity.txt /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

During testing on my MAMP server, the redirect was working perfectly. Once I posted my site on a live domain, the redirect refused to work.

Any suggestions?

I can post my domain name if necessary, although it is not preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get internal server error it can be mod_alias disabled. Check your httpd.conf file for line similar to that `LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so`. If it does not exist then try adding it.